# How can I downgrade python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cmd, command

I downloaded python 3.8.1 unknowing that any later version of python after python 3.6 doesn't support installing tensorflow so now i wanted to know that is there any way to degrade python without uninstalling previous version and directly degrading from any command or any other way

Comment: That depends on how you installed 3.8.1 in the first place. Did you *replace* the existing version, or just install 3.8.1 elsewhere?

Comment: Remove Python 3.8.1 from your PATH variable. Install the version of Python you want to use. Add that location to your PATH variable. This is not an SO question. Better fits https://superuser.com/

Comment: Install the older version along with the current version. And then for tensorflow, select the executable that corresponds to the lower version of Python while building projects. Also, check about [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: @chepner i installed after uninstalling previous one.

Comment: Then do the same thing: uninstall the new one, then (re)install the previous one.

Comment: thanks , for your answer .